# Excel - Highlight and remove duplicate column values in row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am working on a large document that has a couple hundred columns of data.  Many of these rows have duplicate values in the columns that I need to remove.

Here is a sample sheet:

[image]

What I need is to be able to go through each row, find the duplicates in columns B:E and delete all but one of the cells, preferably shifting the rest of the cells left to avoid blank cells. I would need to keep all rows and the rest of their data intact.

So, given the above example, the result would look like this:

[image]

A couple notes:

- The cells in question all appear at the end of each row
- Reasoning: All these values were stored as a list in a single column and split out using `Text to Columns`. I now need to clean it up and remove the duplicates.
- There are thousands of rows and a couple hundred of extra columns that may have duplicates.

Is this possible, even with VBA?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the speed test results for the posted answers (10K rows and 1K columns):

```
VBA 1 - Time:  19.488 sec - RemoveRowDupes (this answer)

VBA 2 - Time: 109.434 sec - dostuff (after turning off ScreenUpdating)

Formula test: N/A (gave up after 5 minutes filling out 10Kx1K range with array, at 9%)
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RemoveRowDupes()
    Dim ur As Range, cc As Long, r As Range, a As Variant
    Dim s As String, i As Long, l As Long, t As Long, tt As Double, tr As String
    tt = Timer
    Set ur = Sheet1.UsedRange
    cc = ur.Columns.Count - 1
    With ur.Offset(, 1).Resize(, cc)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each r In .Rows
            s = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(r)), "|")
            a = Split(s, "|"):
            l = Len(s)
            For i = 0 To cc - 1
                If Len(a(i)) > 0 Then
                    s = Replace(s, a(i), "^^")
                    s = Replace(s, "^^", a(i), , 1)
                    s = Replace(s, "^^", vbNullString)
                    If l > Len(s) Then
                        a = Split(s, "|")
                        l = Len(s)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            s = Replace(s, "||", "|")
            If Right(s, 1) = "|" Then s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
            t = Len(s) - Len(Replace(s, "|", ""))
            r.ClearContents:    r.Resize(, t + 1) = Split(s, "|")
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    tr = "Rows: " & Format(ur.Rows.Count,"#,###") & "; Cols: " & Format(cc,"#,###") & "; "
    Debug.Print tr & "Time: " & Format(Timer - tt, "0.000") & " sec - RemoveRowDupes()"
End Sub
```

---

Test data:

[image: Sheet1]

---

Result - RemoveRowDupes()

[image: Sheet1RemoveRowDupes]

---

Result - dostuff()

[image: Sheet1dostuff]

---

**Note:** this answer can be improved (if needed) by using arrays instead of interacting with the range

Comment: Looks good, @paul bica, but when I run it, nothing happens. I am unfamiliar with VBA, but I added a module to the sheet with my data and pasted your code. How would I actually run this on my range?

Comment: Right now the sheet is just the default Sheet 1, which seems to match what's in your code.

Comment: It doesn't match (it has to be exact): **Sheet 1** has a space before 1. Either remove the space, or go in the VBA editor and look at the top-left pane: you will see 2 names for the same sheet (I know - it can be confusing), but tell me both (exact) names for your sheet with data

Comment: Well, I'm confused then. In the VBA window, the sheet I want is displayed as "Sheet2 (Sheet1)" and the code references "Sheet1.UsedRange".

I have tried changing it to Sheet2.UsedRange, but again no effect.

Comment: Ah, found it! Turns out, I added a general module, but it wasn't actually added to the right sheet. Doing that and changing to Sheet2 worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! (so it works?)

Comment: Yes, it does. And super fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a formula, but the correct values will be in a different location, at least temporarily.  To keep your data in the same location, you can copy the new data and Paste Special > Values over the old data.

This array formula, filled right and down from B7, gives the results shown below:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B1:$E1,,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A7:A7,$B1:$E1),0)),"")`

Note that this is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

A tutorial on how this formula works is given at [Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use VB to process the data in place, you could use the following:

```
Sub dostuff()
Dim myarray As Variant
ReDim myarray(10000)

i = 0 'row iterator

Do While (Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value <> "")
 j = 0 'single item iterator
 k = 0 'column iterator
 m = 0 'stored array iterator
 m_max = 0 'number of unique values on the row

 'iterate single values
 Do While (Range("B1").Offset(i, j).Value <> "")
  temp = Range("B1").Offset(i, j).Value

  'compare to saved
  flag = 0
  m = 0
  Do While (m <= m_max)
   If temp = myarray(m) Then
     flag = 1
   End If
   m = m + 1
  Loop

  'add if unique
  If flag = 0 Then
   m_max = m_max + 1
   myarray(m_max) = temp
  End If

  j = j + 1
 Loop

 'clear existing
 Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Clear

 'write saved
 m = 1
 Do While m <= m_max
  Range("B1").Offset(i, m - 1).Value = myarray(m)
  m = m + 1
 Loop

  i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```